# Should I use MIIM_TYPE in fMask parameter of MENUITEMINFO structure?

Tags: c++, winapi

The documentation says:

[image]

Does that means if I'm creating a string menu item, I should ignore fType and only set fMask  to MIIM_STRING?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what it means.  `MIIM_STRING` should be used instead of `MIIM_TYPE/MFT_STRING`, and `MIIM_BITMAP` should be used instead of `MIIM_TYPE/MFT_BITMAP`.  One reason is because `MIIM_TYPE` cannot use any combination of `MFT_STRING`, `MFT_BITMAP` and `MFT_SEPARATOR` together (as that same documentation states), but `MIIM_STRING` and `MIIM_BITMAP` can be used together.